# NSArray Sorting Floats

Tags: sorting, nsarray

I try hard not to ask questions willy nilly but this is killing me wasted a good couple of hours on it, now so i give in and hope someone can help me please.

I simply can't order my NSArray containing floats correctly the closest i can get is this.

Populating the Array with the following

```
[combosMasterLength addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", finalL]];

    NSMutableSet* set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:combosMasterLength];//Array Final Length
    NSMutableSet* set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:CombosMasterWidth];//Array Final Width
    [set1 intersectSet:set2]; //this will give me only the objects that are in both sets

    NSArray *combos = [set1 allObjects];//cread my combos array with the unique values
    NSArray* sortedArray = [combos sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];//my sorting statment not quite working

    NSLog(@"SORTED ARRAY %@",sortedArray);
```

What i get from my output is : -

```
"1.2",
"1.5",
"12.0",
"2.0",
"2.4",
"3.0",
"4.0",
"6.0"
```

I know what the issue is i just simply have no idea how to sort it and i tried the reference apple docs but they have now gone way over my head, Anyone have any ideas as to how i would sort this so it returns

```
"1.2",
"1.5",
"2.0",
"2.4",
"3.0",
"4.0",
"6.0"'
"12.0"
```

Thanks In Advance 
  Mr H

Comment: What exact type toes the `NSArray` contain? `NSNumber`? `NSString`?

Comment: sorry i am populating buy doing the following [combosMasterLength addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", finalL]];  so it is a string, should i use number?

Comment: You could work with either, although the sorting algorithm needs to be aware of the NSString format or it will sort alphabetically. Added a way to sort as you have it now, but an NSNumber will of course sort more easily and instead require formatting to an NSString on output.

Comment: If you really have the option, I'd go with `NSNumber` instead. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be wanting to sort NSString by numeric value, you'll need to convert the values to a numeric value and compare with that. You can do that, for example, using [`sortedArrayUsingComparator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator:);

```objc
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 @"1.2", @"1.5", @"12.0", @"2.0",
 @"2.4", @"3.0", @"4.0", @"6.0", nil];

NSArray *sorted = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:
  ^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) 
    {
        if ([obj1 doubleValue] > [obj2 doubleValue])
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else if ([obj1 doubleValue] < [obj2 doubleValue])
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        return NSOrderedSame;         
    }
];

NSLog(@"%@", sorted);

> (
    "1.2",
    "1.5",
    "2.0",
    "2.4",
    "3.0",
    "4.0",
    "6.0",
    "12.0"
  )
```

Comment: Hey Joachim, i will drink a Magners in your name tonight :), that works a treat i shall go and investigate the code so i really understand it thank you for your time!!